# Reactstrap Multi-Level Dropdown Ancestors don't close

Tags: drop-down-menu, react-component, reactstrap

I have been developing a multi-level dropdown menu component for the intranet I am building.  Deciding to go with React on this I thought that I multi-level menu would be simple.  Apparently not :)

What I have developed so far works quite well with one exception: When clicking on a NavLink the open menu items do not collapse.

All the CSS classes I have added are appearance only with no positioning statements.  I have built this using a JSON source file and Reactstrap.

Here is the code for my component.

```
class MenuBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
         this.NavListItem = this.NavListItem.bind(this);
    }

    NavListItem = (item, level) => {
        if (item.children.length > 0) {
            return (
                <UncontrolledDropdown direction={level!==0?"right":"down"} nav inNavbar className="menu menu-UncontrolledDropdown" key={"UCD_" + item.pageId}>
                    <DropdownToggle nav caret 
                    className="menu menu-dropdown-toggle item title"
                     key={"DDToggle_" + item.pageId}
                     id={"DDToggle_" + item.pageId}
                     >
                        {item.title}
                    </DropdownToggle>
                    <DropdownMenu  className="menu menu-dropdown-container">
                        <Nav>
                            {item.children.map((listItem) => this.NavListItem(listItem, level + 1))}
                        </Nav>
                    </DropdownMenu>
                </UncontrolledDropdown>
            )
        }

        else {
            return (
                <NavItem className="menu menu-item-container" key={"DDNavItem_" + item.pageId}>
                    <NavLink onClick={() => { this.props.updateCurrentPage(item) }} className="menu menu-link" key={"DDNavLink_" + item.pageId}>{item.title}</NavLink>
                </NavItem>
            )
        }
    }


    render() {
        const setIsOpen = (value) => {
            this.setState({ isOpen: value })
        }

        const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!this.state.isOpen);
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-2 p-3 menu">
                    <div onClick={() => this.props.updateCurrentPage(null)}
                        className="align-top met-logo">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col col-md-6  offset-1 menu ">
                    <Navbar color="light" light expand="md" className="menu menu-bar">
                        <NavbarToggler onClick={toggle} className="menu menu-toggler" />
                        <Nav className="mr-auto" navbar>
                            {this.props.siteMap.siteMapData.map((link) => this.NavListItem(link, 0))}
                        </Nav>

                    </Navbar>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The only problem I have now is the open items do not close when an option is clicked.  I would like preferably to make this stateless and put it in as a functional component ultimately but for now I am pulling Sitemap from Redux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a solution but did come up with a functional workaround that takes very little resource.

In my MainComponent of the SPA I am hosting both the  component as well as the current page component.  What I did, when I realized that clicking off of the menu closed it, was to add a little snippet into the componentDidUpdate() function:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  //work around for menu not closing.
  document.getElementById("rootDiv").click(); 
}
```

This effectively causes the menu to close once the new page has begun loading.  Problem solved.